# Creating a view like Facebook Profile and Wall in an iPhone application

Tags: iphone, view

I have to create an application which contains the same type of view that the Facebook iPhone application has - Profile View and Wall portion. My requirement is to have a question and the user can give an answer with an unlimited number of lines. So obviously I have to use UITableView. Now my problem is deciding my table row height if there are two lines. The answer portion should be small and if the answer portion is big then it should be large with unlimited answers.

Does anyone know how to create this type of table view?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking how to build a UITableView with variable row heights?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're going to want to implement

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

in your UITableViewDelegate. You'll need to compute the height for individual rows and then return those heights in the above function.